# Problem with Firebase UI auth and don't let me sig in

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am starting with Firebase and I have a problem I don't know how to solve.
When I am loggin in the app ask me for the email, but instead ask for pass, just go to the register option. And when I try to register the account it tells me that there is already an account with that e-mail address.
Here is my MainActivity code

```
private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var authStateListener : FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener
    private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(it.data)
        if (it.resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
            if(user != null){
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.msg_sign_in), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        configAuth()
    }
    private fun configAuth(){
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { auth ->
            if(auth.currentUser != null){
                supportActionBar?.title = auth.currentUser?.displayName
            } else {
                val providers = arrayListOf(AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build())
                resultLauncher.launch(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers).build())
            }
        }
    } 

   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.action_sign_out -> {
                AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this,
                            getString(R.string.mssg_sign_out_success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this,
                            getString(R.string.mssg_sign_out_failure), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

Here is my code and the error I get.

```
A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.UserCancellationException: Unknown error
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.data.remote.SignInKickstarter.onActivityResult(SignInKickstarter.java:208)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.KickoffActivity.onActivityResult(KickoffActivity.java:85)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8628)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5316)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5362)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I have tried to solve it by adding the SHA1, but it still doesn't work.